# Creating a matching GUID

Tags: c#, .net, c, qt, guid

A windows server creates a GUID with this array of bytes:-

> *8 146 96 238 162 223 65 74 134 243 14 158 17 155 23 88*

The code used to generate the GUID based on those bytes is the constructor [Guid(byte[] b)](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/guid.cs,b622ef5f6b76c10a).

This generates the GUID **{ee609208-dfa2-4a41-86f3-0e9e119b1758}**

In Qt, a client uses the ported [.NET source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/guid.cs,b622ef5f6b76c10a), which returns a QUuid: -

```
QUuid GetWindowsGuid(const QByteArray& b)
{
    int _a;
    short _b;
    short _c;
    unsigned char _d, _e, _f, _g, _h, _i, _j, _k;

    _a = ((int)b[3] << 24) | ((int)b[2] << 16) | ((int)b[1] << 8) | b[0];

    _b = (short)(((int)b[5] << 8) | b[4]);
    _c = (short)(((int)b[7] << 8) | b[6]);
    _d = b[8];
    _e = b[9];
    _f = b[10];
    _g = b[11];
    _h = b[12];
    _i = b[13];
    _j = b[14];
    _k = b[15];

    QUuid guid(_a, _b, _c, _d, _e, _f, _g, _h, _i, _j, _k);
    return guid;
}
```

Using the same 16 bytes, this produces a UUid whose string is: **{ffff9208-ffa2-4a41-86f3-0e9e119b1758}**

Why does the Uuid string not completely match that of the Windows GUID?

Comment: @RobH, from the Qt Documentation "the GUID is one variant of UUID". The constructor being used in the question does nothing more than populate the internal values: https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/57756e72adf2081137b97f0e689dd16c770d10b1:src/corelib/plugin/quuid.h

Comment: maybe this is close to this problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26911196/extract-serial-from-ssl-certificate

Comment: @SebastianLange, it's a follow up to that question, which I posted yesterday!

Comment: Didn't check the usernames sorry. I'll take a look into it later ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I slightly changed your code, and now it work

```
QUuid GetWindowsGuid(const QByteArray& b)
{
    uint _a;
    ushort _b;
    ushort _c;
    uchar _d, _e, _f, _g, _h, _i, _j, _k;

    _a = ((uchar)b[3] << 24) | ((uchar)b[2] << 16) | ((uchar)b[1] << 8) | (uchar)b[0];
    _b = (((uchar)b[5] << 8) | (uchar)b[4]);
    _c = (((uchar)b[7] << 8) | (uchar)b[6]);
    _d = b[8];
    _e = b[9];
    _f = b[10];
    _g = b[11];
    _h = b[12];
    _i = b[13];
    _j = b[14];
    _k = b[15];

    QUuid guid(_a, _b, _c, _d, _e, _f, _g, _h, _i, _j, _k);
    return guid;
}
```

Comment: I suspected the data types were an issue. Thanks ;O)